# Solving Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I am new to Mathematica and was trying to solve a set of partial differential equations. Mathematica is unable to solve the equations. Is it because the equations are genuinely difficult for it to solve or is there a way to get it solved using Mathematica?

The following is the code that I used:

```
rho[r_,a_,z_]=r+I*a*Cos[z]
rhoc[r_,a_,z_]=r-I*a*Cos[z]
delta[r_,rs_,a_]=r^2-rs*r+a^2
rho2[r_,a_,z_]=r^2+(a*Cos[z])^2
o[t_,psi_,r_,z_]=-M/(r^3*-p[t,psi,r,z])
n[t_,psi_,r_,z_]=-M/(r^3*m[t,psi,r,z])

Assuming[t>0&&0<psi<Pi&&r>0&&0<z<2*Pi,
    DSolve[{-M==r^3 (D[n[t,psi,r,z],t] -(rho2[r,a,z])/(delta[r,rs,a])*D[n[t,psi,r,z],psi]-
    a*(Sin[z])^2*D[n[t,psi,r,z],z]-(I*a*Sin[z])/(rho[r,a,z]*Sqrt[2])*D[p[t,psi,r,z],t]+
    (rho2[r,a,z])/(rho[r,a,z]*Sqrt[2])*D[p[t,psi,r,z],r]+(I*(r^2+a^2)Sin[z])/
    (rho[r,a,z]*Sqrt[2])*D[p[t,psi,r,z],z]),
    -M==r^3 ((-I*a*Sin[z])/(rhoc[r,a,z]*Sqrt[2])*D[o[t,psi,r,z],t]-(rho2[r,a,z])/
    (rhoc[r,a,z]*Sqrt[2])*D[o[t,psi,r,z],r]+(I*(r^2+a^2)*Sin[z])/
    (rhoc[a,r,z]*Sqr[2])*D[o[t,psi,r,z],z]-(delta[r,rs,a])/(2*rho2[r,a,z])*
    D[m[t,psi,r,z],t]-(1/2)*D[p[t,psi,r,z],psi]+(a*delta[r,rs,a]*(Sin[z])^2)/
    (2*rho2[r,a,z])*D[o[t,psi,r,z],z])},
    {p[t,psi,r,z],m[t,psi,r,z]}, {t,psi,r,z}]]
```

Comment: Even if your PDE does have a closed-form solution (often unlikely, considering the nonlinear nature), *Mathematica* will return an unevaluated `DSolve[]` object if it doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: I recommend that you solve this system numerically.